# How to access/or get variable in function?

Tags: php, variables

```
<?php
class test
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods( get_class($this) )
        foreach($methods as $method)
        // question: how to get $get_me in function a() ?
        echo $this->method():$get_me;
    }

    function a()
    {
        $get_me = "good, take me home.";
    }
?>
```

How can i access $get from outside function a() ?

Comment: Why do you get all the methods and call them iteratively? o_O

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

If your function `a` implementation was:

```
function a()
{
    return "good, take me home.";
}
```

you could do:

```
$get_me = $this->a();
```

in your `__construct`

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You cannot reach into a function to get arbitrary variables from it.

Declare the variable as class property or `return` the value from the function, if it must be available outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be declaring $get_me as a property

```
<?php
class test
{
    public $get_me;
    function __construct()
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods( get_class($this) )
        foreach($methods as $method)
        // question: how to get $get_me in function a() ?
        $this->get_me;
    }

    function a()
    {
        $this->get_me = "good, take me home.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `var $get_me;`? What year is on your calendar?

Comment: Still - `private` and `$this->` is lost in `function a()`

Comment: well, the tutorials I learned from OOP said that using var would be equal to using public, not my fault not knowing before that it's not an very accepted way of declaring the method, now I know xD

Comment: I think its 2012 in his calendar, as he is using `__construct` instead of class name. Meantime he went to flashback and accidently wrote `var $get_me` :D

Comment: @aleation: "the tutorials I learned from" --- they were written by not very smart guys. It's not about "acceptance" but about common sense and obsoleteness

Comment: Well maybe they were not smart guys but I had no way to know if those ones were good or not, I just read, tried, worked, and accepted, that's why I try to participate, to learn :D

Comment: @aleation may be you read obselete tutorial? try to google `PHP 5 OOP` or something like this

Comment: And how would I know if they were obsolete or not? it's the problem of being autodidact, you don't know something is wrong unless it fails or someone tell you

Comment: @aleation well I guess most of the articles and tutorials have dates when they were published.

Comment: The problem is I though OOP was only in php5, so I just googled php oop tutorial, and the first result was this one: http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/index.php which doesn't really have a publication date as you can see

Comment: General tip: most random tutorials around the web for PHP are **complete rubbish**. Especially things named like "killerphp". Be aware that PHP has a rather confused past. Anything from the PHP4 days is best forgotten today, and even in PHP5 they pretty much just starting pulling it together since PHP 5.3. The problem is that many tutorials predate PHP 5.3, and even then they were not necessarily good due to the confused state PHP and its users were in. So... stick to the official documentation or known trusted sources. If it's neither and is not dated, be suspicious. :)

Comment: Yeah I've learned that now, I just didn't use the official documentation because I am new into OOP and found it confusing, so wanted a step by step example tutorial, but will have an eye in the future, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = functionname();
functionname()
{

..............//
return variablename;
}
```

So you can get the value outside of the function.

Comment: Hi you just write code and select all coding then press ctrl+k to format the coding then enter your answer